# Z-Index IE 7 and 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

Im working on the following, I've made an nice dropdown menu, the problem is that its working in **every** browser except IE 7 & 8 (or LTE)...

I've been looking down on the questions on stackoverflow and i've tested a lot, but nothing seem to work. So i've been wondering if there is any jquery/javascript fix to fix Z-Index in ie.

I've been looking on a lot of websites, so I would appreactice you not to post any website here from the other questions.

I've changed the z-index to much higher, i have gaven the other divs also z-index but doesnt seem to work.

How it should work: [example1](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/9805/ex2z.png)

How it works now: [example2](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/569/ex1g.png)

Comment: Could you post some of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: z-index is an often an issue in IE

Comment: Ill put it in jsfiddle, if you give me a moment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2vQq/

Comment: there are scripts for ie `z-index` issues. a fiddle will be a good to have.

Comment: @Jai the jsfiddle is in comment

Comment: try to use `Z-index:9999;`

Comment: first div is position:relative inside there div with position:absolute with z-index:1 until 9999 you can refer here for more info http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving position:relative and bigger z-index to the parent of the div containg the username/password dropdown and also postion:relative to the parent of the div that is overlapping the username/password dropdown but less z-index.

Comment: Position relative doesnt help, and i've given the z-index already an index of like 999999

Comment: But did you give `position: relative` and appropriate `z-index` to the parent of your menu element? What is more - I cannot reproduce this problem with IE and your fiddle :(

Comment: make sure that the username/password parent div structure is above the parent of the div that is overlapping. You have to declare position relative to both.

Comment: @Kamo i have the same problem, you might give an look at http://www.grafisign.nl/CAKE

Comment: @Rajiv Can you give a look at the fiddle? maybe you saw something i didnt.

Comment: Your fiidle seems to be working fine... still consider #headerBox{position:relative;z-index:99;}#mainCntr{position:relative;z-index:9;}

Comment: only problem i have left is the textboxes when you are hovering it it goes away;s but ill give it a few looks!

Comment: This problem is because of the structure of you html. You are not using div inside your ul but li. IE faces problem with those structures. Try making the structure simpler. Also use jquery instead of css display.